# What's the difference between the score method on a fitted model, vs accuracy_score from scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'd normally just post this to Stack Overflow, but I thought about it and realised it's not actually a coding question - it's an ML question.

Any other feedback on code or anything else is thoroughly appreciated and welcomed!

[The Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/Aaraeus/kaggle-titanic/blob/master/titanic_model_jupyter_notebook.ipynb)

So I'm doing the titanic problem on Kaggle. I have my four datasets ready to go:

- features_train
- features_test
- target_train
- target_test

With this in mind, I have two questions, though the second one is the important one.

**Question 1: Is my understanding of the next step correct?**

We fit our model on the training data, then we create a prediction (*pred*) which tries to predict based off our *features_test* data. This means that our *pred* and *target_test* datasets should in theory be the same (if the model worked perfectly).

This means that to attest to the accuracy of the model, we can simply compare the results between *pred* and *target_test*, which is what the *accuracy_score* function does from Sklearn.

**Question 2: What's the difference between using the score method of the model, vs the accuracy_score function?**

This is what's confusing me. You can see in cell 97, the first cell under the "Model 1" header, that I use:

```
clf.score(features_test, target_test)
```

This comes out with a result of

> 0.8609865470852018

However, later, I also use:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(target_test, pred))
```

And this also results in

> 0.8609865470852018

How are both of these scores the same? Have I done something wrong? Or are both of these steps basically doing the same thing? How..? Is the `score()` property effectively creating a `pred` Dataframe and checking against that in the background?

Comment: both clf.score and accuracy_score calculate same metric. Both calculate fraction of labels correctly classified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For such issues, arguably your best friend is the **documentation**; quoting from scikit-learn docs on [model evaluation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html):

> There are 3 different APIs for evaluating the quality of a model’s
>   predictions:
>
> - **Estimator score method**: Estimators have a `score` method providing a default evaluation criterion for the problem they are designed to
>     solve. This is not discussed on this page, but in each estimator’s
>     documentation.
> - **Scoring parameter**: Model-evaluation tools using cross-validation (such as `model_selection.cross_val_score` and
>     `model_selection.GridSearchCV`) rely on an internal scoring strategy.
>     This is discussed in the section The scoring parameter: defining model
>     evaluation rules.
> - **Metric functions**: The **`metrics`** module implements functions assessing prediction error for specific purposes. These metrics are
>     detailed in sections on Classification metrics, Multilabel ranking
>     metrics, Regression metrics and Clustering metrics.

In the docs of all 3 classifiers you are using in your code ([logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.score), [random forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.score), and [decision tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.score), there is the identical description:

> **score**(*X, y, sample_weight=None*)
>   Returns the mean accuracy on the
>   given test data and labels.

which answers your 2nd question for the specific models used.

Nevertheless, you should always check the docs before blindly trusting the `score` method coming with an estimator; in [linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score) and [desision tree regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.score), for example, `score` returns the coefficient of determination R^2, which is practically never used by ML practitioners building *predictive* models (it is often used by statisticians building *explanatory* models, but that's another story).

BTW, I glimpsed briefly at the code you link to, and I saw that you compute metrics like MSE, MAE, and RMSE - keep in mind that these are *regression* metrics, and they are not meaningful in a classification setting, such as the one you face here (and in turn, accuracy is meaningless in regression settings)...